# optimize function pointer checking in loop

Tags: c, optimization, function-pointers, function-calls

I have render function, but users can override it by setting function pointer; in every frame I'm checking if it exists or not, and if not I'm using the default function:

```
GK_EXPORT
void
gkScenePerLightRenderPath(GkScene *scene) {
  /* ... */

  do {
    /* ... */
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      modelInst = objs[i];

      if (!scene->renderModelFn)
        gkRenderModel(scene, modelInst);
      else
        scene->renderModelFn(scene, modelInst);
    }
  } while (/* next light */);
}
```

I thought maybe I could write this as below:

```
GK_EXPORT
void
gkScenePerLightRenderPath(GkScene *scene) {
  /* ... */
  GkRenderModelFn renderModelFn;

  /* ... */

  if (!scene->renderModelFn)
    renderModelFn = gkRenderModel;
  else
    renderModelFn = scene->renderModelFn;

  do {
    /* ... */
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      modelInst = objs[i];
      renderModelFn(scene, modelInst);
    }
  } while (/* next light */);
}
```

Which is better? In second version seems like I'm hiding `gkRenderModel` so maybe compiler can't apply optimization? If it doesn't matter for compiler assigning `gkRenderModel` to a pointer then second one seems more optimal because if / else is outside of two loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on several factors:

- if `renderModelFn` (or any other thread, for that matter) modifies the `scene` object at all
- if `gkRenderModel()` is declared `inline` or not.

If it guaranteed to be an external / out-of-line function, and nothing in the loop modifies the object pointed to in the `scene` pointer, then it is better to put the `if` statement before the loop, so it only needs to be evaluated once.

However if there is any possibility that the called function could modify the `renderModelFn` member of the passed-in `scene` object, moving the check before the loop would change the behavior.

Also, calls to function pointers are always out-of-line.  So moving the if statement outside the loop would defeat any inlining possibility.  In that case it would be preferable to keep the `if` statement inside the loop.

Comment: afaik compiler can't inline function pointer but I'm not sure so I didn't mark inline gkRenderModel, should I? It is not edits scene directly but objects pointed by scene if state changes required or for caching purpose

Comment: Correct, functions called via function pointers cannot be inlined, because (by definition) the actual function to be called is not known at compile time.  However, the direct (non-function pointer) call could be inlined in certain circumstances.  Whether this is beneficial or not really depends on the function.  Very generally, it may make sense for very short functions, not so much for larger ones..

Comment: I thought inlining an call made through a function pointer is legal if the compiler could determine the actual function called through static analysis. A silly example: void (*fp)( = &some_function; fp();

Comment: @SoronelHaetir It may be possible (at least in theory) to optimize away the fact that it is a function pointer.  That being said, if it is possible at compile time / static analysis to figure out that one and only one function could possibly be called, then it probably shouldn't be a function pointer in the first place.